# DNN library is not found ssd_mobile_net_v2 in Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm training a hand detection model with Tensorflow and I have a problem.

This is the code to train the model:

```
!cd RealTimeObjectDetection/RealTimeObjectDetection && python Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=/content/RealTimeObjectDetection/RealTimeObjectDetection/Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet/pipeline.config --num_train_steps=5000
```

I have this error:

```
Node: 'ssd_mobile_net_v2_fpn_keras_feature_extractor/model/Conv1/Conv2D'
DNN library is not found.
     [[{{node ssd_mobile_net_v2_fpn_keras_feature_extractor/model/Conv1/Conv2D}}]] [Op:__inference__dummy_computation_fn_15081]
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve the issue by running the following command.

```
!apt install --allow-change-held-packages libcudnn8=8.1.0.77-1+cuda11.2
```

Comment: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2600

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find, this has to do with the newer version of TensorFlow (2.8.0). I was able to resolve the issue by following this - https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/10479#issuecomment-1029626502

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).